# Как заполнить форму до того, как джанго будет ее проверять на валидность

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, forms, django-orm

Нужно отправить форму на сервер.

Имеется несколько полей, по моей логике эти формы скрыты в самом html коде, чтоб юзеру была видна только кнопка отправки уже заполненной формы

Проблема возникла на этапе заполнения полей формы до того, как будет выполнено условие form.is_valid()

## html

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <form action="" method="POST"> {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_hidden }}
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" /></form>
    </body>
</html>
```

## forms

```
class DefaultForm(forms.ModelForm):
    first = forms.CharField(label='first', max_length=120, )
    second = forms.CharField(label='second', max_length=120, )

    class Meta:
        model = Default
        fields = ['first','second', 'third']
```

## models

```
class Default(models.Model):
    first = models.CharField(max_length=120, null=True)
    second = models.CharField(max_length=120, null=True)
    third = models.CharField(max_length=120, null=True)
```

## views

```
def send_form(request):
    #request = request.GET
    #print(request)
    form = DefaultForm(request.POST)

    # вот тут, либо после условия ниже нужно заполнить 
    # форму информацией, чтоб она прошла валидность 
    # и пост запрос пошел на сервер

    if request.method == 'POST':

        if form.is_valid():
            form.first = '1'
            form.second = '2'
            form.third = '3'
            form.save()
            return HttpResponse('Valid')

        else:
            form = DefaultForm()

    return render(request, 'default_app/index.html', {'form': form,})
```

Это какой-то ад!

В документации ничего не нашел, как временно заполнить форму инфой с условием что она будет валидной

В бд вроде понял как сохранять, но передать пустую форму с hidden полями и заполнить ее в коде не знаю совсем

Подскажите пожалуйста

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#Получите или создайте объект, например, объект "а"
#Передайте данные в форму.
f = ArticleForm(request.POST, instance=a)
f.save(commit=False)
f.title = "Ваши данные"
f.description = "Ваши данные"
f.save()
```

Comment: обратите особое внимание на save(commit=False)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Пытаюсь в `instance` передать дикт и получаю `'dict' object has no attribute '_meta'` :с

Comment: Простите за неточность. Имелось ввиду запись из БД.

Comment: Вообще проверка валидности нужна при поступлении данных из запроса. Вы получаете данные, проверяете их на валидность в форме. Далее за валидность данных которые в хотите передать, например, заполнить/перезаписать значение для поля third отвечаете вы.